# XML load into array

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have php file that extracts the following XML from a web service:

```
<deviceList>
    <device 
        name="Low volt light" 
        id="10" 
        type="Z-Wave Switch Multilevel" 
        value="0"
        address="00016922-018" 
        code="" 
        canDim="True" 
        lastChange="26-07-2014 17:31:33" 
        firstLocation="Kitchen" 
        secondLocation="Main" 
    />
    <device 
        name="Light" 
        id="11" 
        type="Z-Wave Switch Multilevel" 
        value="0" 
        address="00016922-019" 
        code="" 
        canDim="True" 
        lastChange="28-07-2014 18:27:56" 
        firstLocation="Bedroom" 
        secondLocation="Main" 
    /> 
</deviceList>
```

To be it seems formatted correctly, but I can not get it loaded into an array or object. I have been through W3School and simliar sources, but even with the examples there, I still cant get i to work. 
Could someone help me here, and maybe also show how the code should be for searching through the array for "id=10" and then display the corresponding "value" (in this example =0)

Comment: Thou shall not believe in "W3School and simliar sources".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, shoudl work ($xml is your xml string) :

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($xml)),1);
```

take a look at this [codepad](http://codepad.org/5uHKNBIg)

Comment: I tryed your code: 

`<?php
//$feed_url = "http://192.168.1.90/ui1/homeseer_rest_api.aspx?function=listdevices&param1=all";
$feed_url = "demoxml.xml";

$content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($content);

//$xml = $feed_url;
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($xml)),1);

print_r($array);
//var_dump($xml)
?>
`
but my array displys: 
Array
(
    [0] => 
)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: $xml should be the file content try this `$xml = file_get_contents($feed_url);` and then the code above (in my answer) to generate the array

Comment: It works kastor mania! Thanks! Now I need to get my head around expressing the value "0" from device with id=13